# What mistake did I made in the bag of words function?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

I'm new in Python. 
Wrote the function to specify the bag of words.

```
DICT_SIZE = 5000
WORDS_TO_INDEX = words_counts
"""INDEX_TO_WORDS = ####### YOUR CODE HERE #######"""
ALL_WORDS = WORDS_TO_INDEX.keys()
```

It's the function:

```
def my_bag_of_words(text, words_to_index, dict_size):
    """
        text: a string
        dict_size: size of the dictionary

        return a vector which is a bag-of-words representation of 'text'
    """
    result_vector = np.zeros(dict_size)
    sentence_tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
    attributes = []
    for i, k in words_to_index.items():
      if k<dict_size:
        attributes.append(i)
    for i in attributes: 
      for k in sentence_tokens:
        if i==k:
          result_vector[attributes.index(i)]=+1
    return result_vector
```

I tried to test the function and it works too

```
def test_my_bag_of_words():
    words_to_index = {'hi': 0, 'you': 1, 'me': 2, 'are': 3}
    examples = ['hi how are you']
    answers = [[1, 1, 0, 1]]
    for ex, ans in zip(examples, answers):
        if (my_bag_of_words(ex, words_to_index, 4) != ans).any():
          print(my_bag_of_words(ex, words_to_index, 4))
          return "Wrong answer for the case: '%s'" % ex
    return 'Basic tests are passed.'
print(test_my_bag_of_words())
Basic tests are passed.
```

After I want to apply it to all text in the Dataset

```
X_train_mybag = sp_sparse.vstack([sp_sparse.csr_matrix(my_bag_of_words(text, WORDS_TO_INDEX, DICT_SIZE)) for text in X_train])
X_val_mybag = sp_sparse.vstack([sp_sparse.csr_matrix(my_bag_of_words(text, WORDS_TO_INDEX, DICT_SIZE)) for text in X_val])
X_test_mybag = sp_sparse.vstack([sp_sparse.csr_matrix(my_bag_of_words(text, WORDS_TO_INDEX, DICT_SIZE)) for text in X_test])
print('X_train shape ', X_train_mybag.shape)
print('X_val shape ', X_val_mybag.shape)
print('X_test shape ', X_test_mybag.shape)
```

And in this case appears the error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-364e76658e6f> in <module>()
----> 1 X_train_mybag = sp_sparse.vstack([sp_sparse.csr_matrix(my_bag_of_words(text, WORDS_TO_INDEX, DICT_SIZE)) for text in X_train])
      2 X_val_mybag = sp_sparse.vstack([sp_sparse.csr_matrix(my_bag_of_words(text, WORDS_TO_INDEX, DICT_SIZE)) for text in X_val])
      3 X_test_mybag = sp_sparse.vstack([sp_sparse.csr_matrix(my_bag_of_words(text, WORDS_TO_INDEX, DICT_SIZE)) for text in X_test])
      4 print('X_train shape ', X_train_mybag.shape)
      5 print('X_val shape ', X_val_mybag.shape)

1 frames
<ipython-input-25-814e004d61c2> in my_bag_of_words(text, words_to_index, dict_size)
     20       for k in sentence_tokens:
     21         if i==k:
---> 22           result_vector[attributes.index(i)]=+1
     23     return result_vector

IndexError: index 5000 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5000
```

Can anybody help me to understand what mistake did I made in the code in the function my_bag_of_words, please?

Comment: The Bag of words principle is used to store a vocabulary in an array. The Python code in realizing such feature shouldn't become a problem. For example, if it's unclear how to add a string to a list, or how to retrieve a list by a key, the problem has to do with python programming itself, but not with bag of words.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `words_to_index` contains higher indices than is your vocabulary limit. You should either increase your vocabulary limit or make sure that `word_to_index` only contains indices < 5000 (e.g. by discarding the least frequent words).